# Is it possible to do a Like Condition in firebaseDatabase with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sql-like

I am trying to do a query with Like condition with String in a Firebase Realtime Database, but I can't manage to do it work

I already tried .startAt and .endAt or equalsTo('%$model%'), with startAt and endAt I able to find models that start with what I searched, but if I search a word that is in the middle of the model, I wont find nothing

```
await databaseReference.child('cars').orderByChild('year').startAt(model).endAt('$model\uf8ff').once().then((result)
```

I wish that was something as 'Like' condition in SQL or 'contains' so I could use it

Comment: Firebase doesn't have SQL like queries.  At best you can do a prefix match.